# Is there a name for a pattern where you build a dependency tree that imitates a filesystem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, architecture

I find myself doing this when I write really big libraries in a dynamically-typed language and want to aggregate exported features near the root of the project. Doesn't have to be Node/JS, but here is an example filesystem for a Node project...

```
src/
    index.js -- imports A/index.js and B/index.js
    A/
        index.js -- imports X/index.js
        X/
            index.js -- imports foo.js and bar.js
            foo.js
            bar.js
        Y/
            index.js -- imports snafu.js and whatever.js
            snafu.js
            whatever.js
    B/
        index.js -- imports alpha.js and omega.js
        alpha.js
        omega.js
```

..where the exported library would imitate the filesystem:

```
const {
    A: {
        X: {
            foo,
            bar
        },
        Y: {
            snafu,
            whatever
        }
    },
    B: {
        alpha,
        omega
    }
} = require('lib');
```

Is there a name for this method of constructing a dependency tree?

**EDIT**: I understand the final result is a tree, but if I document how to contribute to source code, I can't just say "Include modules like a tree," since that doesn't qualify coupling to the filesystem or how to structure exports in each file. I'm looking for a more specific name that captures both the structure of the aggregate, and the way that you build it without having to explain it every time for each project.

Comment: These are called Composites, the Composite Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Composite](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Composite/) pattern.

Compose objects into tree structures to represent part-whole hierarchies. Group of objects is to be treated in the same way as a single instance of an object.

File system example using [Composite](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html).